# Charting tools for reporting

Tags: java, .net, charts

What are the available charting tools in the market for comparison.
It should support both Java and .NET.
It can be open source as well as cost.Please mention the licence type.
Mention it needs any other external softwares like Flash player or other external plugins
Any tutorial/sample links for each if possible/available.
It need not be supporting real time but charts should be pleasing to eyes.

Comment: Perhaps for fun I will write a Scala charting tool so it will work in CLR and JVM. :)

Answer (score 1):

we are using http://www.amcharts.com (among others) which is quite nice and cheap (flash based)

Comment: Even I have used amcharts.Is there anything better than that?

Answer (score 0):

I've used [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/) (commercial) in the past.  It is flash based and uses XML to structure the underlying data, so it is fairly easy to integrate with any language.  There are additional basic APIs available for use with various languages (JSP and ASP.NET included).  Their gallery is at http://www.fusioncharts.com/Gallery/Default.asp

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this list of [Open Source Charting & Reporting Tools](http://java-source.net/open-source/charting-and-reporting) in Java. The most used reporting tool in the Java world is probably JasperReports and it is what I use at work.

Answer (score 0):

I have used JFreeChart and found it to be very useful.  There are a large number of chart types and structures.  Additionally, you have control over the output format, which should allow you to embed in most applications.  We currently use it in a back end process that uses a .Net client front end.

License is GNU LGPL.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to call a remote web service, take a look at [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/). I have seen it being used extensively in some pretty (thick) rich client frontends.

It is licensed under [GNU LGPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html).

The one thing that I would mention about this library is that documentation might be a little scarce and might be a steep learning curve if you're new to it. They do recommend buying [their own developer guide](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/devguide.html). Having said that, if you're up for it, you could try reading their source code and debug what's going on under the covers.